# Can't access an intranet web site from IE

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

There's a intranet website that I'm trying to access through IE, but each time I fill in the address, it just quickly refreshes to the page where I was before. So if I was on www.google.com, and typed in into the address bar 192.168.1.200, it would redirect me back to wwww.google.com.

I've tried accessing on Chrome, and it can load. The problem is I need to use IE, because the intranet page hosts a .NET application.

Comment: Have you verified this behavior within a virtual machine using your default configuration?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cookies and cache?  Have you tried it as another user? How about from Safe Mode?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found out the issue. Sometime ago I installed spybot S&D and it added a list of blocked websites to IE settings, and for some reason the intranet page must have been captured by one of the wildcards. So I restored the IE settings to default, i.e. removed all blocked sites and  now it works.